# How to add css styles on aria-hidden attribute

Tags: html, css

Can an element have styles depending on the `aria-hidden` attribute?

Here is an example of how I want it to work:

HTML:

```
<div aria-hidden="false" class="text">text here</div>
```

CSS:

```
aria-hidden["false"] {
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost:

```
[aria-hidden="false"] {
    color:red;
}
```

This is called [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)